# How to clear the logged in session of Linkedin in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, linkedin-api

I developed Login with LinkedIn by using this [link](http://blogs.innovationm.com/linkedin-integration-in-swift-3-0/), But now I need to clear the logged in session at some specific logic. How to clear that?

I used this URL But getting following error

> https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/invalidateToken

**Error:**

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (LISDKErrorAPIDomain error 400.)

Answer (score 5):

You can clear the web cookies using following code. It Works for me.

```
let cookie = NSHTTPCookie.self
    let cookieJar = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()

    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
       // print(cookie.name+"="+cookie.value)
        cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

***Updated answer from comments:***

What if you set `linkedinHelper` as a var instead of a `let`?  And you re-instanciate it with something like:

```
linkedinHelper = LinkedinSwiftHelper(configuration: LinkedinSwiftConfiguration(...))?
```

***Original incorrect answer:***

Have you tried something like:

```
linkedinHelper.lsAccessToken = nil
```

Comment: No it can't, Cannot assign to property: 'lsAccessToken' is a get-only property

Comment: What if you remove your reference to `linkedinHelper`? And need to reinit another instance to get a new token. In fact your token will be still valid, but won't be saved so you won't be able to reconnect with it?

Comment: linkedinHelper = nil  is not working, I need to create an object instance for this. In fact I need to clear token.

Comment: What if you set `linkedinHelper`as a `var` instead of a `let`? When you re-instanciate it with something like `linkedinHelper = LinkedinSwiftHelper(configuration: LinkedinSwiftConfiguration(...))`? Wouldn't it work?

Comment: Yeah I did the same, But I am not sure this is the right solution to us. There is no proper document about active session clearance from LinkedIn

Comment: Well that's a workaround, waiting for the library to provide correct answer to the active session clearance.